# Eloqua API - Retrieve a list of contacts based on Security Label

Tags: eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

I'm trying to build a dashboard that provides information (aggregates only) about contacts in our Eloqua database, but only those with a specific security label. Is there a way to gather this info using the REST APIs that ELoqua publishes? If not, is it something I can filter on in the Analytics suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the contact security labels are very internal and are not directly available through the api or reporting. A workaround would be to create a shared list for each label, and then add the contact to that list depending on what label they have been assigned, and handle this directly on the label assignment workflow (each time they run through the label assignment workflow, remove them from all shared lists in case their label changes).

You can then access list membership [through the API](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-bulk-2.0-contacts-lists-id-get.html) or bring it in as a subject area in OBIEE, filtering on the appropriate lists.

[image]